# WPF Popup - when to disable, how to keep in relative position to origin control? ;)

Tags: wpf, popup

2 simpl questions.

Given a WPF popup...

- What is a good way to hide it again when it is used like a submenu? WHich event is proper?
- WHat is the way to keep it's position stable relative to the origin control?

THanks in advance ;)

Comment: Since you can put any content you like (buttons, labels, anything else) in a menu control... why aren't you just using a menu?

Comment: Because actually it is a (user) control I am showing there. Not a menu- more like an information box. As in: there is a "connection" control in the status bar, and when you click on it, this popup provides more information (as well a a disconnect / reconnect button). It really is not a menu at all ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `Popup.Opened` and `Popup.Closed` events are fired when the popup is shown and hidden.
2. I would set the `Popup.PlacementRectangle` based on the `Control` origin, which can be obtained using the `Control.PointToScreen` method like so:

`Point location = originControl.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));`

You will need to listen to the `UIElement.LayoutUpdated` event (and probably some other events, too) to determine when the control position has changed.

Comment: 1 ;) thanks, but I meant which event on the popup to TRIGGER it's hide, not how to hide it. 2 - no ;) That is the INITIAL placement. My problem is when I am moving the original window around, the PopUp... stays in place ;)

Comment: Got it - acutally my main problem was that I did not close (STayOpen=true) - nce that was changed, everything worked fine ;)